# Error with parsing on the view?

Tags: java, jsp, rest, spring-mvc

I try to make an web application that will conect with a repository on a server, and i want to print the data on the screen. Actually i try to create a RESTful client. Probably there is a parsing error that doesn't allow me to see the display data
My jsp is the following:

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

  <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1>Get Author</h1>

       <c:if test="${empty author}">
      No records found!
       </c:if>

      <c:if test="${!empty author}">
            <table style="border: 1px solid #333">
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 100px">Id</td>
    <td>${data.id}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>${data.name}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>${data.address}</td>
    </tr>


     </table>
       </c:if>

     </body>
   </html>
```

The controller is the following(i implement the controller with two different ways. The one of them is commented)

```
  @Controller
 public class Contraller {

protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");

private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();



@RequestMapping(value = "/datas", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getDatas(Model model) {


    HttpEntity<Data> entity = new HttpEntity<Data>(headers);

    // Send the request as GET
    try {
        ResponseEntity<DataList> result = restTemplate.exchange("http://www../data/", 
                        HttpMethod.GET, entity, DataList.class);
        // Add to model
        model.addAttribute("datas", result.getBody().getData());

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/personspage.jsp
    return "personspage";
}

/**
 * Retrieves a single record from the REST provider
 * and displays the result in a JSP page
 */

@RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMyData(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model) {


        try{    

            Data results = restTemplate.getForObject("http://www.../data/{id}",
                                      Data.class, id);

            model.addAttribute("data", results);


        }catch(Exception e){


        }
            return "getpage";
}
```

The model:

```
     @XmlRootElement(name = "data", namespace="http://www...")
     @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Data {

private Long id;
private String name;


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setFirstName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

 }
```

In the repository there are 4000 datas. When i give the following URL: localhost:8080/Client_for_rest/data?id=1
(all the id's from 1 to 4000) returns me the view but it doesn't display the data. If i give an id bigger than 4000, i.e. 4001 gives me back that there are no records which is true. According to this i suppose that the client connects with the server side but there is a problem(i suppose with parsing) that it doesn't allow the data to be dispayed on the view. I'm unfamiliar with the Spring MVC framework and i read something about marshaller and castor but i don't how to implement them. Actually i was wondering if there is an easier way to solve my problem. Do i have to use pojo maven dependencies etc?

Comment: in your controller there are some exception blocks right, could you please print the stacktrace there. this is just to check whether the code is getting in there and the exception is suppressed. Also you can keep a break point in getPerson method and check whether the rest call is giving back the desired author. These are some clues i am thinking off to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Also try either running in debugger or adding some logging at just above the line with `model.addAttribute()` so you can see whether the Author object is getting populated with values. Also consider creating the restTemplate via spring xml and add mediaType declarations there and then inject it with annotations to your controller. Better still put all that code into a Service class, so you can test it.

Comment: I just debug the code and i see that i get a 200 http message. That means that are connected but the problem is that i don't get any value. The email, name etc have a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you method return type is string use map object and bindresult as the parameters to that method.

and add elements to that map object.

you can directly access that map object on your jsp page

as an example :

```
@RequestMapping("/locationUpdate.do")
    public String locationUpdate(Map<String, Object> map,@ModelAttribute("location") Location location, BindingResult result) {
        map.put("location", locationService.getLocationByCode(locationcode));
        map.put("locGrp", listLocationGroup());

        return "location/locationAdd";
    }
```

now you can directly access location and locGrp in your jsp